# Directly printing PDF from PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, printing

So, I have this application in Symfony, I use a printer for some stickers, which is fine using JS window.print(), but now, I need to print PDFs and I cannot ask the user to do anything.

Is it possible to directly send the PDF to the printer either from PHP or JS?

I can setup a local server which will be connected on the same network with the printer.

I cannot find nothing about directly printing except some PHP 4.0.4 version extension.

I'm using Symfony 4 with PHP 7.3 and JS for the front end stuff.

Can you please advise if there is a library for PHP or I can skip the print button on window.print() in JS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mean can you send a PDF or anything else directly to a remote Users printer, then unsurprisingly the answer is NO. Its my printer and if you want to use it you have to ask permission

Comment: Why cant you ask the user via Javascript just like yo do with these stickers

Comment: Well, it's a bit of clients' demand, because the users with the PDF have not used to use any kind of technology in their lives. I guess I will look for a solution with the printer in the next 30 minutes or so, and will let the client know that it is not possible and they will have to interact. :)

Comment: Its basically a security thing. If you could do it for legitimate reasons. I could do it for bad reasons

Comment: thank you very much for confirming what I hoped for, less work for me

Comment: There may be legs in @meDom answer, but that does assume that all your potential users have that technology and can tell you where to send the print and I assume give you the permissions to write to their printers hotfolder

Answer (score 0):

Directly this shouldn´t be possible, but what if your Printer has got a smb-hotfolder functionality? Then you could write out files into this hotfolder. Regards

Comment: will check that